# Exact match for all fields in table with excel in Talend

Tags: excel, postgresql, match, talend, lookup-tables

I have a table and an excel wherein I have to compare values for all the fields. If there is a mismatch in the fields with the excel for that row in that column then it should highlight which column is a mismatch with the table field.I m getting all the columns in the rejected instead of only a column with differed value i.e. here only my row 2, column 4 is different from the table. Here is my excel and the table structure. Also I have attached the output needed. Excel Input :

[image]

Table Input :

[image]

Job Design : [image]

TMAP Design : 
[image]

Expected Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS RESOLVED. I put the data into other table and did a case query and joined the other table with the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping seems correct, debug your work following these stemps:

- Make sure that data types are same for both inputs
- Visualize each input using a tLogRow, check out if there is some whitespaces around fields.
- There is a check box in the advanced settings of your input components to trim data and get rid of white spaces.

For the output, Talend cannot highlight cells or color it, think about something else, you can write in a new column the indeces of the unmached cells.

Comment: Somehow I m getting all the values in the rejected link. Alternatively, I included both the excel data into the tables and then applied a query : select a.column1,a.column2,a.column3,a.column4 from pgsbizdim.test11 a inner join
pgsbizdim.test b on a.column1 = b.column1 where a.column2<>b.column2 or a.column4<>b.column4. This does give the result but then I cannot highlight in the table which fields are the exact mismatch. Can this be done in talend ??